# Python is not calling this function and I cannot find out why

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to make this code work and it's not calling my 'makeDictionary' function in my class. I cannot figure out why. Any thoughts?

```
from StringCount import *

def main():
    products = StringCount()
    doc = input("Enter File Location: ")
    doc_object = open(doc, "r").read()
    items = doc_object.split()

    products.makeDictionary(items)

    itemList = products.sortItems()

    print(f"{'Product':^15}{'Quantity':^10}")
    print("-" * 25)
    for p in range(len(itemList)):
        item, count = itemList[p]
        print(f"{item:<15}{count:>10}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit: Sorry for the garbage post, I'm still trying to figure it all out. Here is my class code.

```
from operator import itemgetter

class StringCount:
    def __init__(self):
        self.notes = {}
        self.key = []
        self.value = []

    def makeDictionary(self, items):
        for item in items:
            item.strip('')
            if item == int:
                self.value.append(item)
            if item == str:
                self.key.append(item)
        for i in range(len(self.key) and len(self.value)):
            self.notes[self.key[i]] = self.value[i]
```

EDIT #2: Okay, so to clarify my issue. I'm *not* looking for clarification on the class. Running this program in python I enter the file location, and it skips over the 'makeDictionary' method **entirely**. Now I just don't see why and I am sure there is a small reason. If anyone can help out that would be appreciated.

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do you get an exception? If so, include the full traceback with your question. Can you post the contents of your StringCount module?

Comment: you need to indent main() under your if statement. Also StringCount isn't a known module so that's all I can tell you without being able to test without the contenst of the StringCount module

Comment: `item == int` cannot possibly ever be true, as `item` is a string.  `item == str` cannot be true, either, as `item` won't *be* `str` (the type of all strings), it would be an *instance* of `str`.

Comment: `makeDictionary` is being called, it just doesn't do anything. The conditionals are never true, so noting gets added to the key and value lists. When you hit the `for i` loop, `len(..) and  len(...)` becomes `(0 and 0)` which is `0` and `range(0)` is the empty list. You might want to look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

As @jasonharper points out,

```
if item == int:
```

Won't work. Instead use

```
if isinstance(item, int):
```

Same thing for str

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will be sure to change that. However, in the main function, the method doesn't get called. That is the first issue I am facing.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: @babelr1 it gets called.